# Why isn't \textwidth the width of the text?

Tags: margins

I'm trying to display two things (a bordered box and a shaded box), both of which stretch across the entire text area - that is, since I have 1cm margins, the box should start 1cm from the left edge of the page and continue until 1cm from the right edge of the page.

Unfortunately it seems to start too far in (~1.5cm) and continue too far to the right (~0.5cm from the edge.)  What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[portrait,a4paper,margin=1.0cm,headsep=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\framebox[\textwidth]{test}

\colorbox[gray]{0.85}{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{test}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot the paragraph indent (use `\noindent`), the width of the rules (`\fboxrule`) and the space between frame and text (`\fboxsep`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That worked for the `\framebox`, thanks!  Any suggestions for the `\colorbox`?

Comment: Remove the spaces before and after the `\parbox`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an indentation problem. When you start a new paragraph the text (or everything else) is indented by a certain amount specified in `\parindent`. The solution is to say to LaTeX that doesn't have to indent that line using `\noindent`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[portrait,a4paper,margin=1.0cm,headsep=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\framebox[\textwidth]{test}

\colorbox[gray]{0.85}{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{test}
}
\noindent\framebox[\textwidth]{test}

\noindent\colorbox[gray]{0.85}{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{test}
}

\end{document}
```

I am not sure but I assume that the `\colorbox` is larger than `\textwidth` because of an inner border respect to its content that should be considered when you specify the `\parbox` width

Comment: There is a padding of width `\fboxsep` on either side of a `\colorbox`.

Comment: and a word space either side of the `\parbox` as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the tip, removing the extra spaces fixed another issue I was having...

Answer (score 10):

for the colorbox case add

```
 \usepackage{calc}
```

then

```
\noindent\colorbox[gray]{0.85}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth - 2 \fboxsep}{test}%
}
```

The two `%` are *needed* otherwise the colorbox consists of a word-space a parbox and another wordspace so its content is 2 spaces wider than the inner box, and then colorbox itself adds padding so you want to make the parbox a bit smaller.

Answer (score 3):

### Remarks

1. Specifying `showframe=true` or just `showframe` as the `geometry` option will show the `\textwidth` border. The border will ease you to see whether the contents move beyond it.

   [image]
2. `\colorbox` does not have a frame but only a padding. You need to adjust the parbox size as `\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax`.
3. `\fbox` have both padding and frame, then the parbox size becomes `\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax`.
4. Use `\noindent` to remove the paragraph indentation.
5. `\fboxsep` controls the padding and `\fboxrule` controls the frame thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=7cm,
    paperheight=7cm,
    margin=2cm,
    showframe=true]
{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}



\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \colorbox{red}{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
        {\centering test}%
    }
    
    \noindent
    \fbox{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
        {\centering test}%
    }
\end{document}
```