# width=\textwidth resulting in overfull hbox?

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't \textwidth the width of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64046/why-isnt-textwidth-the-width-of-the-text)

After some gruelling work, I reduced my problem to this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Rolemaster.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The [PDF](http://www.rootdirectory.de/solar/Rolemaster.pdf) included by this snippet is actually a `potrace` of a bitmap, and according to TeX of ~470pt width:

```
<Rolemaster.pdf, id=1, 469.755pt x 91.34125pt>
```

That's why am using the `width=\textwidth` parameter to `includegraphics`, to scale the included PDF down to fit. However, I am getting this warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
```

**Why does this happen, and what would be the correct parameter to `width` to result in max-width fit without a warning?**

I did some trial & error, with (for me) surprising results. Going from the above warning ("15.0pt too wide") I tried:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth - 15pt]{Rolemaster.pdf}
```

Getting:

```
Overfull \hbox (65.00009pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
```

So obviously there's something non-trivial going on behind the scenes, screwing with my numbers. Using *fixed* numbers, I figured that

```
\includegraphics[width=330pt]{Rolemaster.pdf}
```

does what I want, but quite obviously this isn't acceptable since I am not in a mind of peppering my document with "magic numbers" like that. There has to be some constant (or sum of constants) that would result in the proper max width. But I have no idea which one that would be...?

Comment: There's the normal indentation: put `\noindent` before `\includegraphics`

Comment: @egreg: Turn that into an answer and you get the checkmark of honor. I probably wouldn't have thought about indent, ever...

Comment: @egreg: Any idea how reducing the width of the PDF by the excessive 15pt makes it *another* 65pt too wide?

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Agreed.

Comment: @DevSolar You need the `calc` package for that kind of calculation. Without it, it just typesets `-15pt` in front of your graphic.

Comment: @DevSolar If you look at the PDF you'll see that `- 15pt` is typeset. You can't do arithmetic in that way; `width=\dimexpr\textwidth-15pt\relax` would be correct syntactically, but resulting in wrong output, as the picture would be indented.

Comment: Another advice: most of the time, it is better to use `\linewidth` than `\textwidth`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Any hint as for when the two might not actually be the same? (Nevermind... [found it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize).)